# Can't upload to Arduino Uno R3 when using external power

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, gsm, arduino-uno, avrdude

I'm relatively new to Arduino, and here are what I was trying to do.

I have this DFRobot GPS/GPRS/GSM Shield V3.0 and mount it to my Arduino Uno R3 as it is Arduino compatible. So when I was trying to drive the GSM Mode via USB Port as it stated [here](http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/GPS/GPRS/GSM_Module_V3.0_%28SKU:TEL0051%29), I only got to see the GPS Ready in my coolterm monitor, as it should get to the GSM to be ready.

Here is the code I tried to upload

```cpp
// Driving the gsm mode via the USB interface

// # Steps:
// #        1. Turn the S1 switch to the Prog(right side)
// #        2. Turn the S2 switch to the USB side(left side)
// #        3. Set the UART select switch to middle one.
// #        4. Upload the sketch to the Arduino board(Make sure turn off other Serial monitor )
// #        5. Turn the S1 switch to the comm(left side)       
// #        6. RST the board 

void setup()
 {
   //Init the driver pins for GSM function
    pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
   //Output GSM Timing 
    digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
    delay(1500);
    digitalWrite(5,LOW); 
 }
 void loop()    
 {    
    // Use these commands instead of the hardware switch 'UART select' in order to enable each mode
    // If you want to use both GSM and GPS. enable the required one in your code and disable the other one for each access.
    digitalWrite(3,LOW);//enable GSM TX、RX
    digitalWrite(4,HIGH);//disable GPS TX、RX
 }
```

Then, since in its wiki page stated that the **GSM module may need external power (ranged to 7-12V) to power up as it needs 200mA@7v, when calling**, I tried to use 9V/1A external power via the power jack. But then it won't allow me to upload the program to the board.. as it said: 
`avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x43`

I tried to unplug the external power and upload the program again then it works, to the point where only GPS module that was ready again..

So, was using the 9V/1A DC Power Adapter Supply to power up the GSM is the one causing this problem? I've checked my USB cable and the COM port to make sure that everything is fine. Is there any suggestion how to make this works? 
Is 9V too high or is it even not enough power?

I'm new to Arduino so. any help would really be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: This questions refers to hardware and should be discussed on arduino.stackexchange.com, where are already similar questions (e.g. http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/893/arduino-what-happens-if-i-power-the-arduino-with-both-the-usb-and-external-pow)

Comment: thank you for pointing this out! didn't know it earlier thanks!

Comment: why don't you upload you code, plug it in to the external power supply, and restart your arduino?

Comment: Hi @Dan12-16 thank you! I did what you suggested and it worked like a charm. Upload the code, power the external power on and it worked. But, the next time I tried to upload with the external power on it give the same error. Say, is it normal to give the external power after the code is uploaded?